# How to set custom test step in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have trained my model with the input (image) size [None, 400,400,3], but I want to test with a different  input size like [None,512,512,3]. Here my custom training implementation:

```
    my_model = customModel(rgb_mean=self.args.rgbn_mean)        
    ckpt_manager = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer,model=my_model)        
    for epoch in range(self.args.max_epochs):

        # training
        for step, (x,y) in enumerate(train_data):

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                pred = my_model(x, training=True)

                preds, last_logits, loss = pre_process_binary_cross_entropy(
                    loss_bc,pred, y,self.args, use_tf_loss=False)
            if (step)%100==0 and loss < global_loss:
                # tfk.Model.save_weights(my_model,os.path.join(checkpoint_dir,"saved_model.h5"),
                #                        save_format=ckpt_save_mode)
                # # tfk.models.save_model(my_model,os.path.join(checkpoint_dir,"1saved_model.h5"),
                # #                        save_format=ckpt_save_mode)
                # tfk.models.save_model(my_model,checkpoint_dir)
                ckpt_manager.save(checkpoint_dir)
```

Now here my custom test implementation:

```
         root = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer,
                                   model=my_model)
        ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(root,checkpoit_dir,max_to_keep=10)
        root.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
        for step, x in enumerate(test_data):
            preds = my_model(x,training=False)
```

While I test the model resizing with 400x400 it works perfectly, but when I test with other size like 512x512, or 720x1280 it gives me this log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xavie/Documents/Codes/GitHub/efge/main.py", line 76, in <module>
    main(args=arg)
  File "C:/Users/xavie/Documents/Codes/GitHub/efge/main.py", line 70, in main
    model.test()
  File "C:\Users\xavie\Documents\Codes\GitHub\efge\run_model.py", line 198, in test
    preds = my_model(x,training=False)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 968, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\Documents\Codes\GitHub\efge\model.py", line 90, in call
    output = self.batchnorm1(output, training=training)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 964, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2416, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\normalization.py", line 401, in build
    experimental_autocast=False)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 577, in add_weight
    caching_device=caching_device)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 724, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    name=name, shape=shape)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 791, in _preload_simple_restoration
    checkpoint_position=checkpoint_position, shape=shape)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.wrapped_value.set_shape(shape)
  File "C:\Users\xavie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1107, in set_shape
    (self.shape, shape))
ValueError: Tensor's shape (200,) is not compatible with supplied shape (256,)
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.iter
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.beta_1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.beta_2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.decay
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer.learning_rate
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm1.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm1.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.conv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm2.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm2.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm2.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm2.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm2.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.conv3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm3.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm3.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm3.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm3.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm3.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.dconv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm4.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm4.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm4.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm4.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm4.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.dconv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm5.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm5.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm5.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm5.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.batchnorm5.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.dconv3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.predConv1.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.predConv1.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.predConv2.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.predConv2.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.predConv3.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model.predConv3.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.conv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm2.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm2.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.conv3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm3.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm3.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.dconv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm4.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm4.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.dconv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm5.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.batchnorm5.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.dconv3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.predConv1.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.predConv1.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.predConv2.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.predConv2.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.predConv3.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).model.predConv3.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.conv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm2.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm2.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.conv3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm3.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm3.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.dconv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm4.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm4.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.dconv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm5.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.batchnorm5.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.dconv3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.predConv1.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.predConv1.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.predConv2.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.predConv2.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.predConv3.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).model.predConv3.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
```

Here the model:

```
class customModel(tfk.Model):

    def __init__(self, data_format='channels_first', weight_decay=1e4, rgb_mean=None):

        super(customModel, self).__init__()
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
        self.rgbn_mean = rgb_mean

        axis = -1 if data_format == "channels_last" else 1
        #  data_format=data_format,
        self.conv1 = tfk.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(7, 7),
                                       padding="same", use_bias=False,
                                       kernel_initializer=weight_init,
                                       kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay),
                                       strides=(2, 2))  # [8,200,200,16] when the input is 400
        self.batchnorm1 = tfk.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis)

    def call(self, x, training=False):
        x = x-self.rgbn_mean[:-1]
        output = self.conv1(x, training=training)
        output = self.batchnorm1(output, training=training)
        output = tf.nn.relu(output)
        return output
```

What I am doing wrong? how can I fix it? please help me I am new in Keras :(
P.S: I have tried with different Keras save models but I cannot test with different image sizes.

Comment: This error `ValueError: Tensor's shape (200,) is not compatible with supplied shape (256,)` makes me think that the problem is that you're adjusting the input size but haven't adjusted the architecture's input dimensions correctly in some layer. It would be helpful if you posted or linked to your architecture code.

Comment: it is because if the tensor size is 400x400x3, after the first conv2d it turns 200x200x16, but if it is fed with 512x512x3 it turns 256x256x16. How can I  adjust the architecture input, I prepared the input data with tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(). I added the architecture